# PeopleCode reflection for variables

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

Does PeopleCode have something similar to reflection in C# whereby I can access a variable with the variable name stored in a string? I am aware of the @ operator but I think it only applies to fields and records (correct me if I am wrong. I tried and couldn't get it to work.)

Basically, I need to access a Component variable by name with the name itself being variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by @ :

```
Local string &sValue1 = "var1";
```

getting the value :

```
winmessage(@(&sValue1));
```